# Istio SIde car injection

Tags: kubernetes, istio

I need to add an sidecar to run alongside my main container in K8S during runtime. I have currently done this using a script which edits the deployment.yaml to add all necessary parts including the container and any shared volume mounts etc. This currently works but is a bit ugly. I started looking at Istio for automatic sidecar injection but the documentation is a bit unclear to me.

1. Can I provide user defined values for the sidecar when injecting the sidecar ( such as image for the container and paths for shared volume mounts
2. Does it support injection for specific types are will it only inject sidecars for pod types ?

Answer (score 3):

istio, as many other kube-native apps, uses k8s [admission-controller](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2019/03/21/a-guide-to-kubernetes-admission-controllers/) and the [admission-webhooks](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/extensible-admission-controllers/) api to [patch](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/update-api-object-kubectl-patch/) the deployment and inject the sidecar, take a look at https://github.com/istio/istio/blob/master/pkg/kube/inject/inject.go